Blazor Wasm Open 302 Redirect in New Browser Tab
We have a REST API (on one url) that is used by our Blazor spa (on another url) application which exposes a feature to initiate an oAuth handshake against some line of business system for the purpose of obtaining an access token and ultimately accessing data. Some of these third party systems, can at times, have somewhat of a non-standard oAuth implementation and require additional headers or query parameters.  As such the API builds the 302 response which we send back to the Blazor client. Forgive my ignore here as I am not a front-end developer but is it possible within Blazor to capture the 302 response and pop this open into a new browser tab?  Upon searching for an answer it seems there's a way to JS Interop to pop a tab and navigate to a URL but this isn't what I want.  I want the API to return a 302, with say 4 additional headers, and pass that response to the new browser tab?
If that isn't possible should we pop a browser tab open first, then call the API and just have that new browser tab follow the 302?  Seems like Cors is getting in the way?
Thanks!
-mike

Browsers don't allow JavaScript to capture a 302 response and manipulate it directly due to cross-origin and security policies.

@RobertHarvey  So in my scenario I would pop the browser tab prior to Blazor being returned the 302 and then just allow the browser to following it?
